# J meter Record and Playback

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

My question is how should I test a transactions using HTTPS record and controller.I have recorded one transaction,while running the playback option in jmeter the responses getting logged twice for each request.due to this unable to see success response for a transaction. kindly help me on this..

Comment: what you have done? please share some screen and what u are getting in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 thread (virtual user) and 1 iteration on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

[image]

each request will be executed only once:

[image]

You can use [__threadNum() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) to determine current virtual user ID (number) and [`${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to check current Thread Group's iteration.

It might also be the case there are "stale" results, so make sure to `Clear` the listeners output prior to running test one more time:

[image]

Comment: Have given One thread user only..But still getting dual request.....